# How to remove system tables or other tables in SQL Server Link Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, oracle11g

Good day everyone!

I have a link server set up in ***SQL Server 2008 SP3 on Windows 7 64*** for Oracle 11G Express.
I am using Oracle SQL Developer as a database application/Management system.

All is working well except for the long list of tables that's also in the Table tree.
There is a Filter function in SQL Developer, but I do not see the table APEX listed there.

Is there a way to configure SQL Server to that I see onle a specified table in the Link Server?

Here is an image of what I am referring to:

[image]

Thanks for the knowledge - you are making a great difference!

Guy

Comment: If you don't want to see the system table then just hit that minus.  Typically you are working with user tables.

Comment: As you can see the SYSTEM tables I am referring to are from Oracle, right? Because if you look at the image, the system table is not expanded but the table is. The issue here is productive, I have to keep scrolling to find what I am looking  for.

Answer (score 1):

edit your account under security and go to user mapping untick master.

reconnect to sql server.

hope this helps.

or this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190644.aspx

Comment: Good evening Rhian,

Master is already unticked. The current database I am using was attached, not sure if that makes a difference. But the database is checked but not master.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not think to look at SSMS because I was under the impression these were Oracle Tables. I'll try what the link says and post results. Thanks again - Guy

Comment: UPDATE: The above suggestion did not work after restarting SSMS. I also restarted the SERVER to see if it would make a difference. :(

Thanks anyway